# SDL2 not recieving any events at all

Tags: c++, c, sdl-2

In an SDL2 project, `SDL_PollEvents( SDL_Event* e )` doesn't send any events, and allways returns `0`, so I can't process any events. My event processing loop looks fine :

```
SDL_Event e;

while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) > 0 )
{
    //this is never reached !
    printf( "recieved event %d\n", e.type );

    switch(e.type)
    {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            quit = true;
    }
}
```

On the other hand, it compiles fine, drawing works, and I'm sure it's not stuck in an infinite loop ( I made it print out a message at each frame ).

I link against `SDL2` and all other dependencies, I even make `gcc/g++` call `sdl-config --cflags`. How can this be fixed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't call `sdl-config --cflags`. This is for `SDL` ( the first version of the library ), not `SDL2`. It somehow conflicts and stops all events from reaching `SDL_PollEvents()`. Remove it and it should work !

Comment: And if anybody knows how it stops the events, i would be happy to know !

Comment: `--cflags` adds the include path to the SDL1's includes, not SDL2. It's hard to know for sure (esp. since you didn't specify if you include `<SDL2/SDL.h>` or `<SDL.h>`), but it's probably a mismatch in the `SDL_Event` structure (both layout *and* the size itself) between SDL1 and SDL2, leading to undefined behavior.

Comment: @Tim Căs Thans ! I'm on Linux, so I include `<SDL2/SDL.h>`

Comment: No clue then. You can check what `sdl-config --cflags` does manually, though (just run it yourself).